# jQuery to list all anchors on page?

Tags: jquery, html, anchor, match

How can i request all anchors on a single HTML document?

```
$('.notfront article a[href!=http]').attr('href')
```

return only the first match,

```
$('.notfront article a').attr('href').match(/^#\w+/g)
```

also return only the first element.

Comment: what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: no matter what your selector is, .attr will always only return the value of the first. The same goes for any jquery getter method. Without more information on what you're trying to do, it really isn't possible to answer this question other than saying you can't do it like that.

Comment: So are you just trying to return the first anchor element that isn't an external hyperlink?

Comment: yes, i need to collect all of anchors existing on page. something like a table of contents

Comment: i hope someone can explain the downwotes :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getAnchorElements(){
    var elems = [];
    $('.notfront article a').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('href').match(/^#\w+/g))
            elems.push(this);
    });
    return elems;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should select them without the foreach loop.

```
$(".notfront article a[href^='#']" ).
```

Comment: but isn't doing that.